# How would I find the second derivative of the bilinear $B(x,y)=Ax \times y$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

$$B(x,y)=Ax \times y \text{  where } A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2&3 \\ 0 & -1 & 2\\ -1 & 2 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$$

Second derivative is obviously the first derivative of the first derivative. Now this vector product is not exaclty  $\sin (\angle a,b) \| a\| \|b\|$ but a vector, what I do have problems with is putting this into writing, meaning how to I formally do this. I am almost 100 percent sure, by definition is the waay to go.

I was thinking, since this is a continuous bilinear function that: $$B'(x,y)(h^1,h^2)=B(h^1,x^2)+B(x^1,h^2)$$

Comment: Derivative with respect to what?

Comment: I just states: Find the second derivative of the bilinear function...

Comment: @leonbloy I'm surprised that you ask the question "with respect to what?". You have a function defined on a space.  Here it is $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R^3$ and the derivative is the derivative with respect to the variable $(x, y) $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first derivative at point $(x,y)$ is the linear map $$B^\prime(x,y).(h,k) = Ax \times k + Ah \times y$$

The second derivative is constant and equal to the bilinear map from $(\mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R^3)^2$ to $\mathbb R^3$ $$(B^{\prime \prime}(x,y)(h_1,k_1)).(h_2,k_2) = Ah_1 \times k_2 + Ah_2\times k_1$$ where $h_1,k_1,h_2,k_2$ are $3$ dimensional vectors.

Comment: would you think I would need to put this into more detailed terms because of the given matrix >\

Comment: It depends a bit on what was requested... If you want to have all the details, you need to take $h=(h_1,h_2,h_3)$ and $k=(k_1,k_2,k_3)$ and develop all the terms. Good luck for the computation!

Comment: I have an inquiry

Comment: Shouldn't $B''(x,y).(h,k)=Ax \times h + 2 A h \times k + Ah \times y $ because $B'(x,y)(h,k)= Ax \times k + A h \times y= B(x,h)+B(h,y)$ so $(B(x,h)+B(h,y))'=B'(x,h)+B'(h,y)= (B(x,k)+B(h,k))+ (B(h,k)+B(h,y))$

Comment: Michael, you're right to have an inquiry... As I made a mistake. I updated my answer. The second derivative doesn't depend on $x$ or $y$ as the initial map is bilinear.

Comment: I see now, thank you very much !

Comment: That was my honor to discuss with the great Michael Jordan!